# Is there an event on DOM render?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm using this javascript Library [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) to manipulate an external svg in an html page. SVG is very slow to render.

When the svg file is very heavy I can't see the first animation because it's start before rendering. The animation starts on load event, but the page is not yet rendered, so I see the animation ended. Is there a way to capture a rendering event in javascript?

```
// load svg
$('#slide').svg({});
  var svg = $('#slide').svg('get');
  svg.load('slide.svg', {
  addTo: false,
  changeSize: false,
  onLoad: onLoad 
}); 
// animation start when dom is ready not when page is render
function onLoad(){ 
  $('#maskRight').animate({svgWidth: '200'}, 1500)
}
```

Comment: [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: @zzzzBov +1, it's a big difference. Worth mentioning jQuery already uses it internally for animation.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum they only did for a short time (around version 1.6)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is that your Javascript is loaded in the <head> tag, which means the Javascript probably begins running before the body loads. I'd recommend one of the following two options:

jQuery's $(document).ready(handler)

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Or you may perhaps be able to also accomplish this by hooking your above code into the body's onLoad event like so:

```
<body onload="loadSVG">
  <stuff />
</body>
<script>
  function loadSVG(){
    $('#slide').svg({});
      var svg = $('#slide').svg('get');
      svg.load('slide.svg', {
      addTo: false,
      changeSize: false,
      onLoad: onLoad 
      });
  } 
  function onLoad(){ 
    $('#maskRight').animate({svgWidth: '200'}, 1500)
  }
</script>
```

I haven't tested this code, but it's the first thing I'd try if I ran into that problem and didn't want to use jQuery's ready() function for some reason.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've already put the code inside jquery ready() function :(. My problem is that the load event is not sincronyze with the render event